# Problema al ejecutar una Vista en SQL Server

Tags: sql, servidor

tengo un problema al ejecutar una sentencia de una vista en SQL Server.
El problema es que cuando hago una relación con otra tabla para añadir otro campo a la consulta, no me devuelve nada.
Con esta sentencia, me devuelve todos los campos menos uno:

```
SELECT     CASE WHEN _CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.Mano = 1 THEN 'I' WHEN _CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.Mano = 2 THEN 'D' ELSE '' END AS datvar1, 
                      dbo.FACOrderLineSL.Quantity AS envact, dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.Ancho AS datvar4, dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.Alto AS datvar5, 
                      dbo.FACOrderLineSL.CodCompany AS codemp, dbo.FACInvoicingTypeSL.CodInvoicingType AS tipcont, dbo.FACOrderSL.CodOrder AS numped, 
                      dbo.FACOrderLineSL.IDOrderLine AS numlin, dbo.CPRManufacturingOrder.InternalCode AS numalb, dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.Fondo AS datvar6, 
                      YEAR(dbo.CPRManufacturingOrder.PlannedEndDate) AS AÑO, dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.ZonaEnvio AS ENVIO, 
                      dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.FE AS datvar3, dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.TA, dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.FFI, 
                      dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.FFD, dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.LI, dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.LD, 
                      dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.B
FROM         dbo.FACOrderLineSL INNER JOIN
                      dbo.FACOrderSL ON dbo.FACOrderLineSL.IDOrder = dbo.FACOrderSL.IDOrder INNER JOIN
                      dbo.CPRManufacturingOrder ON dbo.FACOrderLineSL.IDManufacturingOrder = dbo.CPRManufacturingOrder.IDManufacturingOrder INNER JOIN
                      dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom ON dbo.FACOrderLineSL.IDManufacturingOrder = dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.IDManufacturingOrder INNER JOIN
                      dbo.FACInvoicingTypeSL ON dbo.FACOrderSL.IDInvoicingType = dbo.FACInvoicingTypeSL.IDInvoicingType INNER JOIN
                      dbo._FACOrderSL_Custom ON dbo.FACOrderLineSL.IDOrder = dbo._FACOrderSL_Custom.IDOrder INNER JOIN
                      dbo._FACOrderLineSL_Custom ON dbo.FACOrderLineSL.IDOrderLine = dbo._FACOrderLineSL_Custom.IDOrderLine
WHERE     (YEAR(dbo.CPRManufacturingOrder.PlannedEndDate) > 2007)
```

Pero con esta otra consulta, al añadir la tabla "_Decorados" y poniéndole un "Case" ya no me devuelve nada.
He probado también sin el "Case" y simplemente diciendo que me muestre un dato de la tabla, pero nada. Si añado la tabla "_Decorados" ya no devuelve nada.

```
SELECT     CASE WHEN _CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.Mano = 1 THEN 'I' WHEN _CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.Mano = 2 THEN 'D' ELSE '' END AS datvar1, 
                      dbo.FACOrderLineSL.Quantity AS envact, dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.Ancho AS datvar4, dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.Alto AS datvar5, 
                      dbo.FACOrderLineSL.CodCompany AS codemp, dbo.FACInvoicingTypeSL.CodInvoicingType AS tipcont, dbo.FACOrderSL.CodOrder AS numped, 
                      dbo.FACOrderLineSL.IDOrderLine AS numlin, dbo.CPRManufacturingOrder.InternalCode AS numalb, 
                      CASE WHEN _Decorados.CodDecorados = ' ' THEN _Decorados.Description ELSE '' END AS datvar2, dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.Fondo AS datvar6, 
                      YEAR(dbo.CPRManufacturingOrder.PlannedEndDate) AS AÑO, dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.ZonaEnvio AS ENVIO, 
                      dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.FE AS datvar3, dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.TA, dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.FFI, 
                      dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.FFD, dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.LI, dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.LD, 
                      dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.B
FROM         dbo.FACOrderLineSL INNER JOIN
                      dbo.FACOrderSL ON dbo.FACOrderLineSL.IDOrder = dbo.FACOrderSL.IDOrder LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.CPRManufacturingOrder ON dbo.FACOrderLineSL.IDManufacturingOrder = dbo.CPRManufacturingOrder.IDManufacturingOrder INNER JOIN
                      dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom ON dbo.FACOrderLineSL.IDManufacturingOrder = dbo._CPRManufacturingOrder_Custom.IDManufacturingOrder INNER JOIN
                      dbo.FACInvoicingTypeSL ON dbo.FACOrderSL.IDInvoicingType = dbo.FACInvoicingTypeSL.IDInvoicingType LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo._FACOrderSL_Custom ON dbo.FACOrderLineSL.IDOrder = dbo._FACOrderSL_Custom.IDOrder LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo._FACOrderLineSL_Custom ON dbo.FACOrderLineSL.IDOrderLine = dbo._FACOrderLineSL_Custom.IDOrderLine LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo._Decorados ON dbo._FACOrderLineSL_Custom.IDDecorados = dbo._Decorados.IDDecorados
WHERE     (YEAR(dbo.CPRManufacturingOrder.PlannedEndDate) > 2007)
```

Comment: He conseguido que me salga algo cambiando algunos INNER JOIN por LEFT OUTER JOIN.
Pero sigue sin salirme todo lo que debería.

Comment: Hola, Urtx. Sería bueno que este avance que lograste, lo demostraras en tu pregunta: Edítala, colocando la query que estás usando ahora, para que los usuarios puedan ayudarte a partir de tu avance (si no los tendrás pegados en la query que ya solucionaste XD).

Comment: Ya está, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Al utilizar `LEFT OUTER JOIN` te trae alguna información porque esta instrucción lo que hace es regresar todos los campos de la tabla de la izquierda y traer de la tabla de la derecha solo los que coinciden con los campos de la izquierda.

Verifica si te falta información en una de la tablas que quieres hacer el `JOIN`. Puedes encontrar mas información [aqui](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx) sobre el uso de combinaciones de tablas en `SQLSERVER`.

Comment: He conseguido que me salga algo cambiando algunos INNER JOIN por LEFT OUTER JOIN. Pero sigue sin salirme todo lo que debería.